# Конкатинация двух массивов по индексу первого

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть два массива и индекс первого массива:

```
index = 1
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8]
```

как вернуть новый массив в котором в первый массив по переданному индексу записывается второй массив, ожидаемый результат:

```
с = [1,6,7,8,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скопируйте массив, и используйте `splice` для вставки

```
let c = a.slice(); // [...a];
c.splice(index, 0, ...b);
```